# Unknown class ingredientLabel in Interface Builder File (xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0)

Tags: ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an application and I continue to get the log output: "Unknown class ingredientLabel in Interface Builder File." ...when I load a specific view.

The ingredientLabel is a label I created in the view.  Here is the relevant code:

in DetailViewController.h:

```
@interface QuickGroceryDetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *ingredientLabel;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ingredientLabel;
```

in DetailViewController.m:

```
@synthesize ingredientLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.ingredientLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }

}
```

No error occurs, and the app runs fine, but I wanted to know why this error is occurring as it could cause problems down the line.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have written something in the custom class attribute of that label.

1. Open the xib where the label is
2. Go to Identity inspector (CMD + ALT + 3)
3. Check the custom class textfield, it there is something just delete it and UILabel will be reestablished
4. Run the code... That line appears when the loadNib,initWithNib, etc. is executed.